# Swagger is not recognizing my OpenApi annotation

Tags: java, kotlin, swagger, openapi, javalin

I'm trying to build a swaggerUI for my API and I'd like to specify pathParameters for my POST method.

My code is setup as follows:

```
app.routes {
    post("/cameras") { context -> postCamera(context) }
}

@OpenApi(
    summary = "Create Camera",
    operationId = "postCamera",
    tags = ["Camera"],
    formParams = [OpenApiFormParam("userId", String::class, true),
                  OpenApiFormParam("groupIds", List::class, true),
                  OpenApiFormParam("cameraName", String::class, true)],
    responses = [
        OpenApiResponse("200"),
        OpenApiResponse("400"),
        OpenApiResponse("409")
    ]
)
private fun postCamera(context: Context) {...}
```

I've been attempting to follow the information written [here](https://javalin.io/plugins/openapi#annotations), but the end result is still the default swaggerUI POST method [image: as seen here]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately for my sanity, the solution was to invalidate my cache in IntelliJ. There was no issue in my codebase.

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped to specify `path` and `method` in the controller handler's annotation.